# How should NULL properties be handled in a CompareTo method?

Tags: c#

I want to compare 2 instances of a class to see if they are equal.

I created this method that is faulty:

```cs
public int CompareTo(AdminEngineTableRowModel other)
{
    int result;
    if (other != null)
    {
        result = NXSTDT.CompareTo(other.NXSTDT);
        if (result == 0)
            result = DALOC.CompareTo(other.DALOC);
        if (result == 0)
            result = DealerID.CompareTo(other.DealerID);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Status.CompareTo(other.Status);
        if (result == 0)
            result = OrderNumber.CompareTo(other.OrderNumber);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Dealership.CompareTo(other.Dealership);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Serial.CompareTo(other.Serial);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Model.CompareTo(other.Model);
        if (result == 0)
            result = OrderDate.CompareTo(other.OrderDate);
        if (result == 0)
            result = StartDate.CompareTo(other.StartDate);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Confirmed.CompareTo(other.Confirmed);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Deposit.CompareTo(other.Deposit);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Engine.CompareTo(other.Engine);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Color.CompareTo(other.Color);
        if (result == 0)
            result = Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem comes when any of the properties, like the first string `NXSTDT` is `NULL`:

```cs
result = NULL.CompareTo(other.NXSTDT); // This causes an error
```

I could create a class **ctor** constructor to initialize all of the properties, or I could edit the `CompareTo` method to check that each property is not null before I test it:

```cs
public int CompareTo(AdminEngineTableRowModel other)
{
    int result;
    if (other != null)
    {
        if ((NXSTDT == null) && (other.NXSTDT != null))
            result = 1;
        if (result == 0)
            result = NXSTDT.CompareTo(other.NXSTDT);
        if ((DALOC == null) && (other.DALOC != null))
            result = 1;
        if (result == 0)
            result = DALOC.CompareTo(other.DALOC);
        // {snip}
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

That just seems like poor programming.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are those properties? Strings?

Comment: Instead of `result = NXSTDT.CompareTo(other.NXSTDT);` use `result = string.Compare(this.NXSTDT, other.NXSTDT);`

Comment: Seems like you don't need the answer @JonathanDodds.

Comment: The OP wrote "The problem comes when any of the properties, like the first **string** NXSTDT is NULL ..." so I'm guessing that NXSTDT is a string.

Comment: Does it really make sense for this type to be comparable in this way?  String inequalty is sketchy as it is (`"nice".CompareTo("rude")` returns -1 meaning that "nice" < "rude" ... I should hope not). But to do that for a series of properties, be they strings or whatever, and in that specific order seems all the more sketchy.

Comment: If you want to see if 2 instances are equal, why don't you use a boolean `Equals` method? It would simplify this code a great deal.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield got an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to write a generic `Compare<T>` method that works will any object that implements `IComparable<T>`. Then you can write the null-handling once and not worry about it again. This does assume that the types you're comparing implement that interface.

```
public static int Compare<T>(T first, T second) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(first, second)) return 0;
    if (first == null) return -1;
    return first.CompareTo(second);
}
```

Then your code would look like:

```
public int CompareTo(AdminEngineTableRowModel other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
    if (other == null) return 1;

    int result = Compare(NXSTDT, other.NXSTDT); 
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(DALOC, other.DALOC);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(DealerID, other.DealerID);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Status, other.Status);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(OrderNumber, other.OrderNumber);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Dealership, other.Dealership);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Serial, other.Serial);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Model, other.Model);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(OrderDate, other.OrderDate);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(StartDate, other.StartDate);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Confirmed, other.Confirmed);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Deposit, other.Deposit);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Engine, other.Engine);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Compare(Color, other.Color);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    return Compare(Name, other.Name);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest short-circuiting by doing `if (result != 0) return result;` instead of repeatedly testing for 0 (and failing) until it gets to the end.  At the end, it's just `return Compare(Name, other.Nane);` One benefit is that you can set a breakpoint on a specific return to see if that's where it's unequal, or on all of them to see when it first determines inequalty.

Comment: Good idea, will update when I get home

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare 2 instances for equality, it is simpler to use a boolean `Equals()` method, like so:

```
public bool Equals(AdminEngineTableRowModel other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    // If applicable, use <Property>.Equals(other.<Property>)
    // For example, to compare strings according to culture
    // and case
    
    return (NXSTDT == other.NXSTDT &&
            DALOC == other.DALOC &&
            DealerId == other.DealerId &&
            Status == other.Status &&
            OrderNumber == other.OrderNumber &&
            ....);
}
```

This way, due to short-circuiting, the method will return false on the first un-equal property value.

Comment: I've been focusing on implementing the [IComparable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-7.0), but this would actually work for what I need.

Comment: Yeah, this method would satisfy the `IEquatable<T>` interface.

Comment: `CompareTo` is used for sorting, not equality. It returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on which object is "less than" the other.

Comment: Also, a `0` result from `CompareTo` does not necessarily mean they are `Equal`; it depends on how the object is defined. When sorting a list of cars, for example, things like make, model, and year would likely be relevant, but color could easily be ignored (should yellow or blue come first?). However, when determining equality, color is definitely a factor. If I order a blue car, I better not get a yellow one.

Comment: @RufusL: Exactly, which is why when the OP says that "I want to compare 2 instances of a class to see if they are equal.", I suggest the `Equals()` method instead.

Comment: Oh, good call - completely missed that. Definitely should use `Equals` over `CompareTo`.

Comment: Old code uses poorly written SQL collects over 1000 records with unnecessary joins, column comparisons, and tables (the way I see it). I rewrote the SQL to be simpler, but I'm not a database guru. I'm just looking to test that I have collected all of the records (checked elsewhere in my code) and that each record has an exact match to a record the old code collected. Should that use `Equals`? I don't know.

Comment: @jp2code: Equals is what I would use in that case. However, if your IDE supports C# 9.0, then Adassko's answer is more apt. The `Record` class was tailor-made for this scenario, assuming each column value is a simple scalar, and not a compound or user-defined type.

Answer (score 1):

If you use at least C# 9 you don't need to actually implement anything, just add `record` keyword to your class:

```
public record class YourClass {}
```

it will automatically generate the `Equals`, `GetHashCode` methods among others and overload the `==` operator so you can simply do:

```
if (instanceA == instanceB) {}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records

Comment: That's cool. Even if I don't use it now, I'm going to remember that trick and add it to my coding collection.

Comment: you definitely should use it if you can, it was designed specifically for scenarios like this "You want to define a data model that depends on value equality."